# FlySQL: completely blank data result

Tags: sql, sql-server

For the SYSDES team database, I'm trying to list the evaluatees and evaluators and the evaluation scores.  I also need to show the full name of evaluatee and evaluator, the evaluation ID, the evaluation item and the score. Sort by evaluatee ID then evaluation item ID.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
  students.stdfname,
  students.stdlname,
  eval_items_scores.eval_item_ID,
  eval_items_scores.score,
  eval_items_scores.eval_ID
FROM
  students,
  eval_items
  INNER JOIN eval_items_scores ON eval_items_scores.eval_item_ID =
    eval_items.eval_item_ID
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit joins and you are missing a join condition for `eval_items`. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: FlySpeed SQL and the data base is Student Team

Comment: "FlySpeed SQL" is a SQL query tool, not a DBMS. To which database system are you connecting? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: I believe mine is Microsoft SQL Server